# stepic：object型に対してのエラーについて(steganography)

Tags: python3

あるPNG形式の画像に対してstepicでdecodeしようとしたところ、以下のようなエラーが出てしまいました。

```
$stepic -d -i xxx.png -o outfile -d
error: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

pngファイルをbytes型のデータとして引数に設定できればいいと思うのですが、その具体的な手段をご教示頂けないでしょうか。

作業環境はUbuntu ver18.04です。
stepicのversionは0.4.1です。

初心者なので基本的な質問で恐縮ですが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: この記事 [Introducing Stepic: Python Steganography in Images](http://domnit.org/blog/2007/02/stepic.html) の例のように指定してみてはどうでしょう？ それから、そのファイルは`stepic`で`encode`されて何かの情報が埋め込み済みになったファイルなのでしょうか？

Comment: ソースコードを眺めて見ますと、`data_out = open(data_out, 'wb')` となっていて、出力ファイルをバイナリモードで開いています。これを `open(data_out, 'w')` とすれば動作するのですが、簡単には `stepic -d -i xxx.png > outfile` とすればよろしいかと思います(デフォルトでは stdout へ出力)。

Comment: 半端に修正されて「Python2でも3でも動かないコード」になっているように見えるので、「自分で直す」ほかなさそうですね。